# Bomb Lab Phase 6 :Stuck on the order of the answer

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

This is asm code for phase_6

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_6:
=> 0x000055555555551b <+0>: push   %r13
   0x000055555555551d <+2>: push   %r12
   0x000055555555551f <+4>: push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555520 <+5>: push   %rbx
   0x0000555555555521 <+6>: sub    $0x68,%rsp
   0x0000555555555525 <+10>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x000055555555552e <+19>:    mov    %rax,0x58(%rsp)
   0x0000555555555533 <+24>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000555555555535 <+26>:    mov    %rsp,%r12
   0x0000555555555538 <+29>:    mov    %r12,%rsi
   0x000055555555553b <+32>:    callq  0x555555555ab3 <read_six_numbers>
   0x0000555555555540 <+37>:    mov    $0x0,%r13d
   0x0000555555555546 <+43>:    jmp    0x55555555556d <phase_6+82>
   0x0000555555555548 <+45>:    callq  0x555555555a77 <explode_bomb>
   0x000055555555554d <+50>:    jmp    0x55555555557c <phase_6+97>
   0x000055555555554f <+52>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0000555555555552 <+55>:    cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x0000555555555555 <+58>:    jg     0x555555555569 <phase_6+78>
   0x0000555555555557 <+60>:    movslq %ebx,%rax
   0x000055555555555a <+63>:    mov    (%rsp,%rax,4),%eax
   0x000055555555555d <+66>:    cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
   0x0000555555555560 <+69>:    jne    0x55555555554f <phase_6+52>
   0x0000555555555562 <+71>:    callq  0x555555555a77 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000555555555567 <+76>:    jmp    0x55555555554f <phase_6+52>
   0x0000555555555569 <+78>:    add    $0x4,%r12
   0x000055555555556d <+82>:    mov    %r12,%rbp
   0x0000555555555570 <+85>:    mov    (%r12),%eax
   0x0000555555555574 <+89>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000555555555577 <+92>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x000055555555557a <+95>:    ja     0x555555555548 <phase_6+45>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x000055555555557c <+97>:    add    $0x1,%r13d
   0x0000555555555580 <+101>:   cmp    $0x6,%r13d
   0x0000555555555584 <+105>:   je     0x5555555555bb <phase_6+160>
   0x0000555555555586 <+107>:   mov    %r13d,%ebx
   0x0000555555555589 <+110>:   jmp    0x555555555557 <phase_6+60>
   0x000055555555558b <+112>:   mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
   0x000055555555558f <+116>:   add    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000555555555592 <+119>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000555555555594 <+121>:   jne    0x55555555558b <phase_6+112>
   0x0000555555555596 <+123>:   mov    %rdx,0x20(%rsp,%rsi,8)
   0x000055555555559b <+128>:   add    $0x1,%rsi
   0x000055555555559f <+132>:   cmp    $0x6,%rsi
   0x00005555555555a3 <+136>:   je     0x5555555555c2 <phase_6+167>
   0x00005555555555a5 <+138>:   mov    (%rsp,%rsi,4),%ecx
   0x00005555555555a8 <+141>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x00005555555555ad <+146>:   lea    0x202c7c(%rip),%rdx        # 0x555555758230 <node1>
   0x00005555555555b4 <+153>:   cmp    $0x1,%ecx
   0x00005555555555b7 <+156>:   jg     0x55555555558b <phase_6+112>
   0x00005555555555b9 <+158>:   jmp    0x555555555596 <phase_6+123>
   0x00005555555555bb <+160>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x00005555555555c0 <+165>:   jmp    0x5555555555a5 <phase_6+138>
   0x00005555555555c2 <+167>:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%rbx
   0x00005555555555c7 <+172>:   mov    0x28(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555555cc <+177>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rbx)
   0x00005555555555d0 <+181>:   mov    0x30(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00005555555555d5 <+186>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
   0x00005555555555d9 <+190>:   mov    0x38(%rsp),%rax
   0x00005555555555de <+195>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
   0x00005555555555e2 <+199>:   mov    0x40(%rsp),%rdx
   0x00005555555555e7 <+204>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rax)
   0x00005555555555eb <+208>:   mov    0x48(%rsp),%rax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x00005555555555f0 <+213>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rdx)
   0x00005555555555f4 <+217>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
   0x00005555555555fc <+225>:   mov    $0x5,%ebp
   0x0000555555555601 <+230>:   jmp    0x55555555560c <phase_6+241>
   0x0000555555555603 <+232>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
   0x0000555555555607 <+236>:   sub    $0x1,%ebp
   0x000055555555560a <+239>:   je     0x55555555561d <phase_6+258>
   0x000055555555560c <+241>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
   0x0000555555555610 <+245>:   mov    (%rax),%eax
   0x0000555555555612 <+247>:   cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
   0x0000555555555614 <+249>:   jle    0x555555555603 <phase_6+232>
   0x0000555555555616 <+251>:   callq  0x555555555a77 <explode_bomb>
   0x000055555555561b <+256>:   jmp    0x555555555603 <phase_6+232>
   0x000055555555561d <+258>:   mov    0x58(%rsp),%rax
   0x0000555555555622 <+263>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x000055555555562b <+272>:   jne    0x555555555638 <phase_6+285>
   0x000055555555562d <+274>:   add    $0x68,%rsp
   0x0000555555555631 <+278>:   pop    %rbx
   0x0000555555555632 <+279>:   pop    %rbp
   0x0000555555555633 <+280>:   pop    %r12
   0x0000555555555635 <+282>:   pop    %r13
   0x0000555555555637 <+284>:   retq   
   0x0000555555555638 <+285>:   callq  0x555555554f00 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

By analysing, i have to input 6 non identical digits and are less than 6 and should separated by space. That looks like a linked list, so every node links to the next node which should be bigger than previous node. So randomly entered 1 2 3 4 5 6. As I understand they should be in ascending order, so everything should work well, but i keep getting exploded. Where am i doing it wrong?

I tried to understand and analyze the diassemblied code. I have an idea that this is a linked list that should contain 6 elements that point to the next node which should be bigger than the previous node. Elements should not be less than 0 and greater than 6. So orderdered answer 1 2 3 4 5 6 should be a correct answer but i keep getting exploded. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to look at the linked list data in memory, starting with the first element at `0x555555758230` which the rip-relative LEA puts into RDX.  It's normally not in sorted order, that would be too easy.